# Create New Event using Outlook Api in PHP (using POST method)

Tags: php, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am creating new event in php using POST method in Outlook API. I followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial to implement GET events method. Authorization code I am using is following

```
$oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => 'APP ID',
      'clientSecret'            => 'APP Password',
      'redirectUri'             => 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/authorize',
      'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
      'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
      'scopes'                  => ' Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Calendars.Read.Shared'
    ]);
```

to get token this is the code

```
  $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $_GET['code']]);
```

Now to create Event from PHP app to outlook calendar. After Getting token, I have written following code to create new event with POST method.

```
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events";
        $data_json = '{
            "subject": "Lets go for lunch",
            "body": {
              "contentType": "HTML",
              "content": "Does late morning work for you?"
            },
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            },
            "location":{
                "displayName":"Harrys Bar"
            },
            "attendees": [
              {
                "emailAddress": {
                  "address":"ehteshamanwar_86@hotmail.com",
                  "name": "Ehtesham Anwar"
                },
                "type": "required"
              }
            ]
          }' ;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken->getToken(),
        "Content-length: ".strlen($data_json))
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($result);
```

the response of this call is

```
 {  "error": {
"code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
"message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "7accd0e6-428c-4d71-....",
  "date": "2018-09-06T11:18:29"
}  }
```

[Microsoft app in dev center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnZI5.png)

Please help how can I resolve this issue

Comment: How do you solved the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

> "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",

Just as the message said, there are User authentication issue.

Use the console or any other way to output the Token. And check your redirectUri in dev center and project setting.

Consider efficiency, I suggest you follow the [Microsoft Graph SDK for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) to make all of our Event API Calls.

Comment: I am receiving token,  redirectUri is "http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/authorize" in app, and after the post method call it redirects to "http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.9/authorize?code=Mfeddf723-54f3.......&state=50ea......"  , is there any problem here?
If you need token I can provide you with that to.

Comment: It is not a complete token: EwBwA8l6BAAURSN/FHlDW5xN74t6GzbtsBBeBUYAAX3kxuk8f5k4CIImOnBswbOmpsWXIprX2LvhYIiodysV60/Kpvorj3Ql3CRXT1dsNutFiPXXq74OFXpzlfQ7YipEZofOeYSYwyGNuYHXf9be38b5OKk5WI/jVTelQB6S5LnyyNDs3JCVbEOJtw2qxldWZ3toXDZZUnbg2RFLXMwkM3x2JUoiR68A/jM1/4gg+e+4NTLg0p9/O8AITnGIWmwBrRSDw0nwaZd+B7HRKOeRo6jcXSOx8QBOSkl+4Xn97eS/Petrl9PGCFrOdy+q1toPl3LsOFIZSNeOGfRGjS68MvfLDA1xl2JrOLdsm9/enSr6zKfPFCYXjL29BMUEi6YDZgAACLa+QUdCACvsQAIhK1Gw1ECO/ANSiewdl4m9FB8ArEsETI71DoDoJfQKi5hy93aaNydNwXe6yYf1CJZLMWllIwLB+CJ/qYQOwG.......

Comment: I have added dev center app screen shot please review it too.

Comment: Pls execute this line too:echo 'Auth URL: '.$oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl(); I want to see the output ot it. And it should be better use http://localhost:8000/authorize as the redirectUri too. The one you use maybe cause some encoding issue.And add the following to your scope:openid profile offline_access User.Read

Comment: this is the output. 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=24083d09a2cfbd4eb8b2b48ed44888cd&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20User.Read%20Mail.Read%20Calendars.Read&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FCodeIgniter-3.1.9%2Fauthorize&client_id=48d95347-8473-40ce-80ee-e55ef19703c7

Comment: Compare your output with mine and the official docs's, it seems some parameter is missing in your url. Official docs:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview. Mine auth url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=2eafe17b-0ab0-47d6-93bb-e59243224695e&
redirect_uri=http%3a%2%2flocalhost%3a55065%2fresponse_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&
scope=openid+email+profile+offline_access+User.Read+Mail.Send+Files.ReadWrite&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3XTjGsY590rjzg&nonce=636723388861288306.ODZlYj

Comment: state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3XTjGsY590rjzg&nonce=636723388861288306.ODZlYj is missing in my URL, can you tell me how you are making object $oauthClient

Comment: My token is returned from the Graph client library. But based on current data, must have some parameter need to pass to curl_setopt……I am not sure what we need to add now. Just an suggestion, use the php graph client sample and compare the config with your current request way.

Comment: Try to add 'Calendars.Read (Admin Only)' and 'Calendars.ReadWrite (Admin Only)' to your applications on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and why not using the graph php lib from microsoft? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php#authenticate-with-the-microsoft-graph-service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Office 365 you might have to Register application for user authentication on Azure.

You can do so simply by following the steps on the tutorial below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=1

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31991013)